# python plot doesn't display a window on ubuntu

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

When I run this simple code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1,2,3,4])
plt.ylabel('some numbers')
plt.show()
```

I don't get any window. I tried to save it into file and it works, but I want to display window with plot on screen.

I'm using python version 2.7.3. And I'm working on Ubuntu.

How can I show the window/plot?

Comment: check your backend in `matplotlibrc` config file

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed numpy? matplotlib requires numpy version 1.4 or later. You could get the installation steps from [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question.